# Viewport a la Angry Birds?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Not sure if that's the right name for it, but I'm looking for a way to implement zooming in my game.

Essentially the game should zoom in on my character during the moving and shooting phase (its like Worms), but zoom out when the character has shot (preferably by following the shot, like Angry Birds does).

Can Corona/Lua do something like this?

Comment: You might want to post on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ instead of/as well as.

Comment: Ah, apologies, wasn't aware that section existed.

Comment: It's semi new, there's all sorts of other Stack Exchanges now :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything should be in a display group and you can run transitions to scale the group.  Something like:

```
transition.to(gameGroup,{time=500, xScale = 2.0, yScale=2.0})
```

to zoom in.  You should also research cameras to help keep your player centered on the screen.